# sklearn CountVectorizer TypeError: refuses 'ngram_range' other than (1,1)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, typeerror, n-gram

Is there a bug in Python 2.7.3 in sklearn CountVectorizer? A previous post mentioned an earlier bug. Here is my simple input and I get a TypeError.

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>> ngram_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='char_wb', ngram_range=(2, 2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ngram_range'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you have an older version of `sklearn` installed. The keyword argument `ngram_range` is introduced in version [`0.12`](http://scikit-learn.org/0.12/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) (e.g. does not exist in version [`0.11`](http://scikit-learn.org/0.11/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I've entered the command: sudo apt-get install python-sklearn, but it seems to not have had any effect. Could I still not have the most recent sklearn vesion? What is the command for tat?

Comment: I had used apt-get and it must have not installed the most recent. I tried again with easy_install and it got the most recent version. Thanks for pointing this out.